# How can I use github api to decide the dependencies between two commit?

Tags: github, relationship, commit

I know that GitHub offer an api to compare two commit like https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#compare-two-commits. However, I wonder if I can use api on GitHub to decide the relationship between two commits. See the following commit graph:

```
A ---> B ---> C ---> D 
└--->E---------------┘
```

From the above, commit A is the predecessor of commit B & commit E, while commit B is not predecessor of commit E. 
Considering my situation, judge whether commit A is predecessor of commit B is enough. Thanks a lot!

Comment: GitHub has an API, but the GitHub API is not really the best way to decide this. The better way is to check the repository out and then make the comparison using Git itself.

Comment: Thank you, Tom! Could you give me the GitHub API, I think it may work. Since if I using git, I'll have to deal with a large dataset by hand. So many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One of my instructors suggests that, we can download the commit message to the sql database, then query the relationship. since github api message contains commit's previous_commit, we can use this to construct the relationship.